# Mapbox GL JS: Add layer below US state labels?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox GL JS and I would like to add a choropleth layer, but show US state labels above the layer.

I have read [this blog post](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/labels-on-top/) about how to add layers underneath map labels. However, the example given explains how to add layers underneath *city* labels:

```
map.addLayer({
   ...
}, 'place_label_city_small_s'); // Place choropleth layer under these labels.
```

But how do I adapt this for US state labels? What should I use instead of `place_label_city_small_s`?

Is there a way that I can ensure all map labels appear on top of the layers?

Comment: Try `place_label_other`, what map style are you using light or street??

Comment: I'm using the light map style, thanks. `place_label_other` still seems to hide the state labels (and city labels too).

Comment: Try `background`

Comment: Did `background` work??

Comment: If you go into mapbox studio and start editing the basemap style you are using, you can then find the first feature that is a label, and use that name in your code. It is different for all basemap styles.

Answer (score 3):

It is explained [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-layer-in-stack/), you identify the label layer via:

```
var layers = map.getStyle().layers;
// Find the index of the first symbol layer in the map style
var firstSymbolId;
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    if (layers[i].type === 'symbol') {
        firstSymbolId = layers[i].id;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly! For the "Light" style the OP is using the first symbol layer is `waterway-label`.